# how to remove OutputCache programmatically for ascx?

Tags: asp.net, outputcache

I have a page1.aspx:

```
<%@ Register src="uc1.ascx" tagname="UcHead" tagprefix="uc1" %>
```

and uc1.ascx using the `OutputCache`:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="18000" VaryByParam="*"  %>
```

How can I click a button in another page2.aspx to remove `OutputCache` for uc1.ascx or page1.aspx?

When the OutputCache is in page1.aspx, I can use the following code to remove the OutputCache:

```
string url = "/page1.aspx"; 
HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem(url);
```

But it does not work when the OutputCache is in uc1.ascx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok try this

In the page load of your user control put:

```
HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("myCacheKey", DateTime.Now);

BasePartialCachingControl pcc = Parent as BasePartialCachingControl;
pcc.Dependency = new CacheDependency(null, new string[]{"myCacheKey"});
```

Change the key to whatever you want it to be for your control.

Then in the code of the event that you want to clear the cache put:

```
Cache.Insert("myCacheKey", DateTime.Now);
```

I saw this solution at http://dotnetslackers.com/ASP_NET/re-63091_ASP_NET_clear_user_control_output_cache.aspx

I tested it and it seems to work, although I do have to refresh the page once again after I call this like to see the updated control content.

Comment: It works When the OutputCache is in page1.aspx. But it does not work when the OutputCache is in uc1.ascx.

Comment: I updated my answer see if that works. I had never tried to output cache user controls before so I am interested in how to do it as well.

Comment: It's great! Thank you very much! And my small tip: the code should be put at the end of the page_load of UC after gridview binding, otherwise a gridview does not refresh outputcache correctly.